# Accordion collapse/expand all in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working with JQuery Mobile and I have a bunch of accordions on my page. I want to expand/collapse all the accordions at once, at the click of a button. How can this be done?

Comment: Please post some code so we can see how you are doing this.

Comment: This is the basic way to create a collapsible(accordion) and I have many such repetitive divs, but it doesn't have any function that I can call to expand/collapse.

    `<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
        <h3>Header swatch A</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible content with a themed content block set to "A".</p>
    </div>`

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of code are you using? This is not a real question, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does something like this work?

- http://jsfiddle.net/UUhMa/
- http://jsfiddle.net/UUhMa/3/ ( without the foreach )

JS

```
$('#openAll').on('click', function() {
    $('.openMe').each(function() {
        var coll = $(this);
        coll.trigger('expand');
    });
});
$('#closeAll').on('click', function() {
    $('.openMe').each(function() {
        var coll = $(this);
        coll.trigger('collapse'); 
    });
});
```

Alternate JS ( without the foreach ):

```
$('#openAll').on('click', function() {
    $('.openMe').trigger('expand');
});
$('#closeAll').on('click', function() {
    $('.openMe').trigger('collapse');
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="collapsible" class="openMe">
   <h3>Hello 1</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" class="openMe">
   <h3>Hello 2</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" class="openMe">
   <h3>Hello 3</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>
<br />
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="openAll">Open All Collapsible</a>
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="closeAll">Close All Collapsible</a>
​
```

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible.html

Looks like this wont work on a set as only one can be open at a time:

- http://jsfiddle.net/UUhMa/1/

Set Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html

Comment: Could you shorten it by removing the .each? For example $('.openMe').trigger('expand') and $('.closeAll').trigger('collapse')?

Comment: Nice, I love jQuery Mobile, haven't had much of a chance to use it properly, but it always looks so pretty!

Comment: Thanks to you and @Andy, this code works fine. However, I'm adding the accordion dynamically as in [here](http://bit.ly/Lxn7JD) but it doesn't work. Also, I'm not even able to fire an alert in that case.

Comment: I don't know exact release when this thing was changed, but if it doesn't work you should use `collapsible` instead of `trigger`.

Answer (score 3):

for some reason the above solution is not working for me
ie;
$('.openMe').trigger('collapse'); and $('.openMe').trigger('expand'); is not working.

So, I have rewritten the method slightly.

The Javascript code will look like this

```
$('#openAll').on('click', function() {
        $(".ui-collapsible-heading").removeClass("ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed");
        $(".ui-collapsible-content").removeClass("ui-collapsible-content-collapsed");
        $(".ui-collapsible-heading a").addClass("ui-icon-minus").removeClass("ui-icon-plus");
```

});

```
$('#closeAll').on('click', function() {
        $(".ui-collapsible-heading").addClass("ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed");
        $(".ui-collapsible-content").addClass("ui-collapsible-content-collapsed");
        $(".ui-collapsible-heading a").removeClass("ui-icon-minus").addClass("ui-icon-plus");
```

});

ie; adding and removing the required classes using jquery.

[jsfiddle for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/jnelsonin/jy9m7/6/)

Comment: `trigger` could be replaced with `collapsible`.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this post while trying to figure out why it wouldn't work on a collapsibleset which, as mentioned by Phil, isn't possible since only one can be open at a time.

It probably isn't the appropriate solution, but I was able to mimic the look of a collapsibleset while making it a simple collapsible by adding the following CSS to the collapsibles themselves:

```
.collapsible { margin: -1px 0 0; border-radius: 0; }
```

This then allowed me to open and close all of them using

```
$('.collapsible').collapsible('expand');
$('.collapsible').collapsible('collapse');
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all of your collapsible divs share a common parent:

```
$("#parent-id").children().collapsible("collapse");
```